# Why does my tkinter Listbox keep moving?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been trying to create a simple questionnaire in tkinter (Python 3) and I'm having a problem where my listbox moves whenever I edit a label underneath it.

To illustrate what I mean, here are two pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiGZm.jpg

Can anyone help me understand why the box doesn't stay still?

```
class Questionnaire(Frame):
# GUI


def __init__(self, master):

    # Initialise

    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.grid()
    self.createProgSelect()
    self.createQuestions()

def createProgSelect(self):

    # Degree programme label

    lblProg = Label(self, text='Degree Programme:', font=('MS', 8,'bold'))
    lblProg.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=NE)

    # Listbox

    self.listProg.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
    self.listProg = Listbox(self, height= 3)
    self.listProg.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=E)

    # Scrollbar

    scroll = Scrollbar(self, command= self.listProg.yview)
    scroll.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky=W)

    # Listbox items

    for item in ["CS", "CS with", "BIS", "SE", "Joints",""]:
        self.listProg.insert(END, item)

    self.listProg.selection_set(END)


def createQuestions(self):

    # Strongly agree

    lblStrAgr = Label(self, text = 'Strongly \n Agree', font=('MS', 8,'bold'))
    lblStrAgr.grid(row=3, column= 4, rowspan=2)

    # Partly agree

    lblStrAgr = Label(self, text = 'Partly \n Agree', font=('MS', 8,'bold'))
    lblStrAgr.grid(row=3, column= 5, rowspan=2)

    # Partly disagree

    lblStrAgr = Label(self, text = 'Partly \n Disagree', font=('MS', 8,'bold'))
    lblStrAgr.grid(row=3, column= 6, rowspan=2)

    # Strongly disagree

    lblStrAgr = Label(self, text = 'Strongly \n Disagree', font=('MS', 8,'bold'))
    lblStrAgr.grid(row=3, column= 7, rowspan=2)

    self.varQ1 = IntVar()

    # Label for question 1

    Q1Label = Label(self, text='1. Short text')
    Q1Label.grid(row=5, column=0)

    # Radio buttons for question 1

    R1Q1 = Radiobutton(self, variable=self.varQ1, value=4)
    R1Q1.grid(row=5, column= 4)

    R2Q1 = Radiobutton(self, variable= self.varQ1, value=3)
    R2Q1.grid(row=5, column= 5)

    R3Q1 = Radiobutton(self, variable= self.varQ1, value=2)
    R3Q1.grid(row=5, column= 6)

    R4Q1 = Radiobutton(self, variable= self.varQ1, value=1)
    R4Q1.grid(row=5, column= 7)
```

Sorry for the slightly stupid question.

Comment: The problem is hard to diagnose without fully reproducible code, so have a wild guess: what happens if you supply `colspan=3` when you do `Q1Label.grid`?

Comment: The box is not moving... the entire window is getting wider to accommodate the longer text.  I would apply a `width` to `Q1Label` so that it doesn't not automatically resize itself.  You can then add in a second line  to handle longer text.

Comment: Well, that worked exactly how I wanted it to. Didn't think of something so simple. Thanks. (Changed colspan).

Comment: @Jkdc Please put your (correct) answer in an answer box, so Hassan can accept it, you get credit, and reviewers will know this is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a grid. A grid implies that all of the items in a particular column are of the same width, and all of the items in a particular row are the same height. If, for example, a given column grows in width, all the columns to the right will naturally move over to make room.

Your listbox is in column 3. Your label is in column 0. When you configure the label to have very wide text it causes column 0 to expand to accommodate the label. This causes all of the following columns to move over.

My guess for a solution is to have your label span three columns (`...grid(..., columnspan=3)`), though I don't know for certain exactly what you are trying to accomplish.